# A map of atomic counters in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which is triggered by a dynamoDB (table "A") and for each retrieved performs counting and aggregation to another dynamoDB table (table "B").
My use case requires a map of atomic counters,

Let's assume an item in dynamoDB table "A" looks like:

```
Item 1: {'user': 'foo', 'letter': 'a'}
Item 2: {'user': 'foo', 'letter': 'b'}
Item 3: {'user': 'foo', 'letter': 'b'}
Item 4: {'user': 'foo', 'letter': 'c'}
Item 5: {'user': 'bar', 'letter': 'a'}
Item 6: {'user': 'bar', 'letter': 'd'}
```

(Note: my real use case has thousands of 'users', each user has thousands of items, and my "letters" range is of ~400)

Therefore I expect table "B" to look like:

```
Item 1: {'user': 'foo', letter_map {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 1}, total_letters : 4}
Item 2: {'user': 'bar', letter_map {'a': 1, 'd': 1}, total_letters : 2}
```

I have a AWS Lambda function that hanldes a dynamoDB stream from table "A" and creates a put_item to table "B" with the following `UpdateExpression`:

```
UpdateExpression: 'ADD letter_map.#letter :val, total_letters :val',
ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#letter' : RetreivedTableAItem['letter']}
ExpressionAttributeValues: {':val': 1}
```

The problem is that put_items on table A can happen concurrently, I hoped the atomic counter will help me solve the concurrency issues, but I observe that the `total_letters` counter is indeed atomic and performs well, while the `letter_map` map of counters is getting reset if I have concurrent writes to the same user,

Note: on user creation I create an empty `letter_map`, to handle the limitation mentioned [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=686547#686547).
I also tried initializing my entire `letter_map` to 0s on all available letters, didn't work either.

Is this the normal behavior or is it a bug?

If it is normal, any suggestion on how to achieve this task of map of counters?

Comment: what is you hash/range keys of table A?

Comment: "while the letter_map map of counters is getting reset if I have concurrent writes to the same user" - did you faced this kind of problem?

Comment: I made things shorter for simplicity, but my primary partition key is equivalent to "user" (it is actually a hashed `userID`) and my primary sort key is a `letterID`.

And yes, I have faced this problem.

Comment: so if you don't have concurrent write the letter map counter works? And what do you mean by reset? Letter map counters become 1 again?

Comment: Yes, if I write one item each time and wait it works. Not sure about "reset", but what I observe is that after two exact series of writing 1000 items to table "A", table "B" is not the same (i.e not deterministic). I assume it "resets" or uses data which is out-dated.

Answer (score 0):

if your hash key is 'User', then put_item on table 'B' on same user cant happen concurrently (by lambda). each lambda can work on one dynamo db shard, and on each shard it process the items serially (to protect ordering). so if 'User' is your hash key, than its guaranteed that User 'X' will be always on the same shard.

i think that if you are facing this kind of issue (getting reset) its because other error that you have in your code.

from aws [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/):

The Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams records sent to your AWS Lambda function are strictly serialized, per shard. This means that if you put two records in the same shard, Lambda guarantees that your Lambda function will be successfully invoked with the first record before it is invoked with the second record. If the invocation for one record times out, is throttled, or encounters any other error, Lambda will retry until it succeeds (or the record reaches its 24-hour expiration) before moving on to the next record. The ordering of records across different shards is not guaranteed, and processing of each shard happens in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, for the reference to the doc, I guess the problem is actually not with the `put_item` on table B, but with the original `put_item` on table A. 
Different records with the same `userID` but different `letterID` are probably spread across different shards, thus serialization is not guaranteed for that scenario. Not sure how to approach this issue though...

Comment: 'Different records with the same userID but different letterID are probably spread across different shards' - if you have a good spread on you hash key, this wont happen... so you should have a good spread.. maybe this is your issue